# Access preferences from different ViewModels

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, xamarin.essentials

I have SettingsViewModel with:

```
  public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel, ISettingsViewModel
  {
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
    }

    private string _gaugeColor;
    public string GaugeColor
    {
      get => Preferences.Get("GaugeColor", "#17805d");
      set
      {
        Preferences.Set("GaugeColor", value);
        this.OnSettingsChanged();
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SettingsChangedEventArgs> SettingsChanged;
    private void OnSettingsChanged() => this.SettingsChanged?.Invoke(this, new SettingsChangedEventArgs(this.Settings));

    public Settings Settings { get; private set; }
  }
}
```

I set color by HEX string.

Then in PanelViewModel I have:

```
private Color _gaugeColor;
public Color GaugeColor
{
  get => Color.FromHex(Preferences.Get("GaugeColor", "#17805d"));
  set
  {
    _gaugeColor = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

Now if I change HEX string from Settings view in UI, color does not change in PanelViewModel until I restart an application.
Question is: How to make color change in PanelViewModel right after it has been changed in SettingsViewModel?

I have tried to add this into PanelViewModel, but apparently this creates a new instance of SettingsViewModel and Color does not follow into PanelViewMode. Maybe there is some direct solution and I am using Xamarin.Essentials wrong?

```
public PanelViewModel()
{
  this.SettingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
  this.SettingsViewModel.SettingsChanged += OnSettingsChanged;
}

private Color _gaugeColor;
public Color GaugeColor
{
  get => Color.FromHex(Preferences.Get("GaugeColor", "#17805d"));
  set
  {
    _gaugeColor = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}

private void OnSettingsChanged(object sender, SettingsChangedEventArgs e)
{
  this.GaugeColor = Color.FromHex(e.Settings.GaugeColor);
}

private SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel { get; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.preferences?view=xamarin-essentials

Comment: As you store data in Preferences you can just call OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GaugeColor)) in your OnSettingsChanged. And don't need local SettingsViewModel .

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev I think I need somehow to notify PanelViewModel about changes done in SettingsViewModel? Is there some way to do that?

Comment: yes-but you've already notified this.SettingsChanged?.Invoke and OnSettingsChanged processes this event

Comment: you could use MessagingCenter to broadcast a message, and any relevant VM's could subscribe to that message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question is: How to make color change in PanelViewModel right after it
> has been changed in SettingsViewModel?

Yes, a simple method is to use  [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

The `MessagingCenter` class implements the `publish-subscrib`e pattern, allowing message-based communication between components that are inconvenient to link by object and type references. This mechanism allows publishers and subscribers to communicate without having a reference to each other, helping to reduce dependencies between them.

You can refer to the following code:

In `SettingsViewModel.cs`, we can publish a message in the constuctor of it,just as follows:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public SettingsViewModel() {

        Title = "SettingsView";

        MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Color>(this, "Hi", Color.Yellow);
    }

}
```

And in `PanelViewModel.cs` ,we can subscribe to this message:

```
public class PanelViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public PanelViewModel() {

        Title = "PanelView";

         MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, Color>(this, "Hi", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----->  receive color= " + arg); 
      
         // here ,we can use the received color to update the UI 

        });
    }

}
```

Note:

Once we receive the color, we can use the received color to update the UI, and the  color field in the  `PanelViewModel.cs`  should implement interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please inform how it should be done if there are several properties to update? Can I somehow combine several properties or should I create several `MessagingCenter.Send` events?

Comment: For some reason I can't get it work. I will create a github repo to model the behavior and try to ask a new question